# MS Access table list order is defaulted in subform

Tags: sorting, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a subform with a table, where some fields are restricted to tables. The tables are sorted in the correct order, but when it is used in the subform, it is set to default sorting. I can't find the location of the correct place to set the sorting criteria. I tried using query instead of a table, but i could only sort either by ascending or descending (or nothing). All three options resultet in undesired order. Example of the phase being sorted as default despite the table settings:

[image: Right order]

[image: Wrong order]

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gustav suggests, add another field to your t_Phase table, which will be the order you want this list to appear in the drop-down (make sure it is a number field):

[image]

Supply the numeric order:

[image]

In your other table, you can use the ID field from your t_Phase table by selecting it through the lookup wizard:

[image]

[image]

Move across the ID and the new "Order" field you just created:

[image]

Use the "Order" field as the field you want to use for sorting and make sure "Ascending" is selected:

[image]

Continue through the wizard:

[image]

Select the field that has the data you want to go in to the record of your table (I assume it's the ID field rather than the Order field, so make sure ID is selected):

[image]

Finish the lookup wizard and go in to Datasheet View on your table and check that the dropdown is now in numeric order. You've probably noticed a problem though as it is showing both the ID and the Order columns:

[image]

To hide the unnecessary Order column, go back in to Design View and click on your phase field to select it.

At the bottom should be a "Lookup" tab. Click on this and notice the Column Widths property... it's showing 2 different widths values; the first one is the ID field and the second one is the Order field. Set the Order field to 0cm to hide it. I'd then recommend setting the remaining Id field width to something that will be wide enough to show all your ID field's options. Then I'd set the List Width property to the same width.

[image]

8cm, for example:

[image]

This should result in something like the following, which is hopefully what you're after.

[image]

If you're not adding a lookup field to the design structure of a table, but are instead using a combo-box on a form or subform, the principle is pretty much the same; you'll just have to amend the combo-box properties from the form's Property Sheet "Format" tab instead:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. It is very much what i tried. I also solved it exactly as you suggested here in the latter part, by adding another column to sort on. I just thought it could be done without it. The strange part was that it was actually sorted by the "val" function but the sorting was kinda removed when used in a subform. But sorting on another column worked through all. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Combo- and listboxes always contain text, thus your column is not sorted numeric.

To have a numeric sort, add a column with the number only and - in the source - sort only on that. If you don't the number separately, create it from this expression:

```
Val(Mid([PhaseField], 7))
```